In the Catholic view, why did the Devil and his angels rebel?
As stated above. I know the out-of-pocket answer is "pride", but I'm curious.
The angels all had full knowledge of the choice and the resultant consequences, yet a third rebelled.
Was it exclusively pride that led them to this decision, or something else? It seems a remarkably unwise decision for a being that knows unequivocally that it will result in eternal torment and separation from God.
We can make the obvious argument that this is an awful lot like us, but the angels all had far more information than us. Angels don't need faith, they've all personally met God and know who He is without any doubt. They're timeless and never experienced moments of weakness.
They made the decision in utterly ideal circumstances. Was it truly pride and pride alone that led to this?

Do you prefer "official church teaching" (which probably doesn't exist and definitely isn't satisfying) or "saintly speculation"

I prefer Church teaching, but I'm open to exploration where it doesn't contradict Church teaching :)

Not sure this is clearly a duplicate?

In the Catholic view, why did the Devil and his angels rebel?
The Catholic Church does not have an official stance on this subject matter, but some Catholic theologians have presented some possibilities concerning it.
First of all, let us cover the facts we know for certain.
The Catechism of the Catholic Church affirms, “The Church teaches that Satan was at first a good angel, made by God” (CCC 391). Initially Satan was good and some traditions go so far as to give him the name Lucifer, or “light bearer,” when he was a bright angel of light (cf. Isaiah 14:12-15).
We know almost nothing about Satan’s activities before his fall. What we do know is that there was a great battle in Heaven, recorded in the book of Revelation:

7 And there was a great battle in heaven, Michael and his angels fought with the dragon, and the dragon fought and his angels:
8 And they prevailed not, neither was their place found any more in heaven.
9 And that great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, who is called the devil and Satan, who seduceth the whole world; and he was cast unto the earth, and his angels were thrown down with him. - (Revelation 12:7-9)

Jesus himself declared in the Gospel: “I have observed Satan fall like lightning from the sky” (Luke 10:18).
This battle appears to have occurred sometime before the creation of Adam and Eve, as Satan was already present in the Garden of Eden in his fallen state.
These facts, so far, are all that we can know with certainty. The exact reason of Satan’s fall remains unclear to us, but there seems to be three main theological opinions as to why.

Satan’s desire of independence of God and equality with God.

Lucifer sinned by desiring to be “as God.”

The Devil refused to bow down to a nature lower than themselves in the Second Person of the Trinity in the human nature of Christ and that all the hierarchy of heaven must bow in adoration before the majesty of the Incarnate Word; and this, it is supposed, was the occasion of the ”pride of the Devil” and his fallen demons.



The sin which by many of the best authorities is regarded as being actually the great offense of Lucifer, to wit, the desire of independence of God and equality with God. It is true that this seems to be asserted in the passage of Isaiah (14:13).
Although St. Thomas regards the desire of equality with God as something impossible, he teaches nevertheless (loc. cit.) that Satan sinned by desiring to be "as God", according to the passage in the prophet (Isaiah 14), and he understands this to mean likeness, not equality.
Although nothing definite can be known as to the precise nature of the probation of the angels and the manner in which many of them fell, many theologians have conjectured, with some show of probability, that the mystery of the Divine Incarnation was revealed to them, that they saw that a nature lower than their own was to be hypostatically united to the Person of God the Son, and that all the hierarchy of heaven must bow in adoration before the majesty of the Incarnate Word; and this, it is supposed, was the occasion of the pride of Lucifer (cf. Suarez, De Angelis, lib. VII, xiii). As might be expected, the advocates of this view seek support in certain passages of Scripture, notably in the words of the Psalmist as they are cited in the Epistle to the Hebrews: "And again, when he bringeth in the first-begotten into the world, he saith: And let all the angels of God adore Him" (Hebrews 1:6; Psalm 96:7). And if the twelfth chapter of the Apocalypse may be taken to refer, at least in a secondary sense, to the original fall of the angels, it may seem somewhat significant that it opens with the vision of the Woman and her Child. But this interpretation is by no means certain, for the text in Hebrews 1, may be referred to the second coming of Christ, and much the same may be said of the passage in the Apocalypse. - Devil


Thanks for the broad and balanced answer :)

The true narrative is that God presented Adam to the angelic host and ordered them to adore God's new creation but Samael or Satan refused stating that a being who is made from fire cannot prostate before a being made from dust and so did other angels

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Where can you substantiate your claim?

@KenGraham, the reason for the fall was pride and there is no way 66 million angels agreed to side with the devil because he desired to be like God, it beats logic. The angels are highly intelligent beings and knew this is Lucifer a created being and this is God, the  supreme being, it had to be a command that tested their humility, a command that required them to adore Adam which they refused but other angels did and they still do it through Christ
